# Embed C Struct - Function In Python

Tags: python, c

I'm writing a little MySql C program which should be embed in Python code. For demonstration purposes program will execute MySql INSERT and SELECT commands on database. How can I make this struct and function to work in python code and pass MySql result to python or cdef variable.

Can someone help, thanx in advance !

**HERE IS MY C WORKING CODE:**

**HEADER FILE: "chi2.h"**

```
struct _MYSQL
{
char *server;
char *user;
char *password;
char *database;
char *table;
char *ptr_statement;
char *user_input;
MYSQL *connection;
MYSQL_RES *result;
};
MYSQL_RES *_GET_MYSQL(struct _MYSQL *DATA);
```

**C CODE FILE: "chi2.c"**

```
#include "/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h"
#include "mysql.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "chi2.h"

MYSQL_RES *_GET_MYSQL(struct _MYSQL *DATA)
{
DATA->result = NULL;
DATA->ptr_statement = NULL;
DATA->connection = mysql_init(NULL);

/* Connect to database */
if (!mysql_real_connect(DATA->connection, DATA->server, DATA->user, DATA->password, DATA->database, 0, NULL, 0))
{
mysql_close(DATA->connection);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(DATA->connection));
exit(1);
}

/* Get MySql query */
DATA->ptr_statement = malloc(sizeof(int) * 16);   // int is 4 bytes * 16 (64 bytes * 8 = 512 bits)
snprintf(DATA->ptr_statement, *(DATA)->ptr_statement, "INSERT INTO hash (hash_name) VALUES ('%s')", DATA->user_input);
if(mysql_query(DATA->connection, DATA->ptr_statement))
{
free(DATA->ptr_statement);
DATA->user_input = NULL;
mysql_close(DATA->connection);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(DATA->connection));
exit(1);
}
mysql_commit(DATA->connection);
free(DATA->ptr_statement);
DATA->user_input = NULL;

DATA->ptr_statement = malloc(sizeof(signed short int));   // short int is 2 bytes (16 bits)
sprintf(DATA->ptr_statement, "SELECT * FROM %s", DATA->table);
if (mysql_query(DATA->connection, DATA->ptr_statement))
{
free(DATA->ptr_statement);
mysql_close(DATA->connection);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(DATA->connection));
exit(1);
}

mysql_commit(DATA->connection);
free(DATA->ptr_statement);
DATA->result = mysql_use_result(DATA->connection);
return DATA->result;
mysql_close(DATA->connection);
mysql_free_result(DATA->result);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
struct _MYSQL *DAT;
MYSQL_ROW ROW;
MYSQL_RES *RESULT = NULL;

DAT->server = "localhost";
DAT->user = "test1";
DAT->password = "test1";
DAT->database = "test";

DAT->table = "hash";
DAT->user_input = "HELLO :D";
RESULT = _GET_MYSQL(&(*DAT));
while ((ROW = mysql_fetch_row(RESULT)) != NULL)
printf("%s - %s \n", ROW[0], ROW[1]);
}

mysql_free_result(RESULT);
RESULT = NULL;
ROW = NULL;
DAT->table = NULL;
DAT->user_input = NULL;

//fflush(stdin);
//system("clear");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: We are not here to do your assignments/homework/write your code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: One option is to create a C function that takes all the necessary input variables that go into your struct, and use that as your entry point to python. Such a function is easy to integrate with Python, in contrast to a struct.